# Are there some default fonts (ttf) in python Pillow?

Tags: python-imaging-library, truetype

In the documentation of Pillow (PIL Fork). One font type is mentioned in [ImageDraw module tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text) that is "FreeMono", for example `fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 40)`.

It seems possible to get other fonts' ttf locally on the machine and use it with Pillow, but I was wondering are there any other testing fonts (other than "FreeMono") for testing and playing around with this tool, like some bolder fonts, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
Pillow/Tests/fonts/ArefRuqaa-Regular.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/AdobeVFPrototype.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/KhmerOSBattambang-Regular.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/NotoNastaliqUrdu-Regular.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/DejaVuSans-bitmap.ttf
Pillow/Tests/fonts/TINY5x3GX.ttf
```

Search in the repository with:

```
find . -name "*.ttf"
```

Comment: Amazing thanks! I found 550+ fonts not in the PIL package, but at local `/usr/share/fonts/truetype` all of them are seems to be working.